# HTML text align in div

Tags: html

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  This<br>is<br>a<br>test!
</div>
```

I use the above code to align the text in the middle of a div. Code works good, however, is there a way to make it appear on the middle of the div but still one letter to appear above the other?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in another element, and center that element. The centered element will keep the default `text-align: left`.

For example:

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
}
.test div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>This<br>is<br>a<br>test!</div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div>This<br>is<br>a<br>test!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two div to accomplish this. The first div will center align the text and the inner div will align to the left.

```css
.test {
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;background-color: red;">
  <div class="test">
    This<br>is<br>a<br>test!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the text with another `<div>`, make it `inline-block` and align its contents to the left:

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="wrapper">
      This<br>is<br>a<br>test!
  </div>
</div>
```